# I2C Detect shows that Rasberry Pi keeps assigning the same address to 2 devices

Tags: display, i2c, adafruit

I'm trying to hook up 2 Adafruit Quad Alphanumeric displays to my Rasberry Pi 3 B+.

From what I understand, all I need to do is hookup the displays in series to the SDA SCL outs, and the I2C chip is able to dynamically assign addresses to the devices I hookup.

No matter what I tried, when I hooked up my devices, and I run `sudo i2cdetect -y 1` they would both be shown as assigned to address 0x70. If I hooked up the displays independently, they would both work, and be assigned address 0x70. But when I attached 2, they would both still be assigned 0x70. I was still able to send text commands to them either independently or both wired up, but they would both show the same text.

Is there a way to debug the I2C chip on the RaspberryPi to confirm it is working correctly?

I have tried reinstalling the OS twice.

I’ve attached a diagram of how I have wired up my displays in case I got it wrong somehow.

[image: Diagram of 2 Adafruit Quad Alhpanumeric Displays in Series Connected To Raspberry Pi.]

Comment: look for the address selection solder points A0 A1 and A2 - look at about page 61 in the adafruit PDF for these things

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Pi does NOT assign addresses. They are set by the device.

Some devices have configurable addresses.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. Will do some digging and try answer my own question.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to have two different addresses you need to configure them with jumpers :

- This board/chip uses I2C 7-bit addresses between 0x70-0x77,
  selectable with jumpers https://www.adafruit.com/product/1912.
- If a jumper is shorted with solder on the display, that sets the address
  https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-led-backpack/changing-i2c-address.